# Create new image file of 750 x 380 px on Android phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I need to create a blank 750 x 380px image on my android phone - then paste some images and text onto the blank image. Simple as this sounds - spent over 72 hours searching the Web with no way to this. Pixlr and all other mobile image editing apps can only edit existing images - but won't allow you create new ones with fixed canvas size. Suffice it to say I haven't got access to a computer now and must do this on my Samsung android mobile. Help guys - I'm about to really really freak out.

Comment: First- don't freak out. That would be silly.
Second- we are all using Android devices, which means that Google Search is built in and pretty simple to use.

See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Don't freak out. That would be silly.

I just tried (for your question) an app named [PhotoSuite 4 Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.msgsreg). I was able to start a new project, specify its pixel dimensions and add a text layer. Seems to be what you're looking for.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]